# Retrieving child folder name using DataFolder property in SOAP api marketing cloud gives me 404 error

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap

Retrieving child folder name using DataFolder property in SOAP api marketing cloud gives me 404 error stating File or directory not found, The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7e0cca04-57bd-4481-864c-6ea8039d2ea0</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://'mysoapurl'.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth
            xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">XXXX
        </fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg
            xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>DataFolder</ObjectType>
                <Properties>ID</Properties>
                <Properties>Description</Properties>
                <Properties>ParentFolder.Description</Properties>
                <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
                <Properties>ParentFolder.CustomerKey</Properties>
                <Properties>Name</Properties>
                <Properties>ContentType</Properties>
                <Properties>ParentFolder.Name</Properties>
                <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
                <Properties>ParentFolder.ObjectID</Properties>
                <ns1:Filter
                    xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="ns1:SimpleFilterPart">
                    <ns1:Property>Name</ns1:Property>
                    <ns1:SimpleOperator>IN</ns1:SimpleOperator>
                    <ns1:Value>DataExtension's Name</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:Filter>
                <QueryAllAccounts>false</QueryAllAccounts>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My error response :

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Your SOAP envelope is calling the `DataFolder` object (and properties) and not `DataExtension`. Which one are you looking to call? Can you please provide a bit more insight into exactly what you are looking to get from your call.

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake, its for DataFolder object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you had conflicting namespaces and was causing a 'Bad Request' error, hence the 404.

You were using `s:` and `a:` in your header tag instead of the declared `SOAP-ENV:` and `xsd:` that you had in the envelope.  Once this was altered, it worked as expected.

See below working example from your code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <xsd:Action SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</xsd:Action>
        <xsd:MessageID>urn:uuid:7e0cca04-57bd-4481-864c-6ea8039d2ea0</xsd:MessageID>
        <xsd:ReplyTo>
            <xsd:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</xsd:Address>
        </xsd:ReplyTo>
        <xsd:To SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">https://{{et_subdomain}}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</xsd:To>
        <fueloauth
            xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{dne_etAccessToken}}
        </fueloauth>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg
            xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>DataFolder</ObjectType>
                <Properties>ID</Properties>
                <Properties>Description</Properties>
                <Properties>ParentFolder.Description</Properties>
                <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
                <Properties>ParentFolder.CustomerKey</Properties>
                <Properties>Name</Properties>
                <Properties>ContentType</Properties>
                <Properties>ParentFolder.Name</Properties>
                <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
                <Properties>ParentFolder.ObjectID</Properties>
                <ns1:Filter
                    xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="ns1:SimpleFilterPart">
                    <ns1:Property>Name</ns1:Property>
                    <ns1:SimpleOperator>IN</ns1:SimpleOperator>
                    <ns1:Value>Folder1</ns1:Value>
                    <ns1:Value>Folder2</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:Filter>
                <QueryAllAccounts>false</QueryAllAccounts>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

That being said though, there is a lot of room for optimization in your envelope that you may want to explore as it seems to be more of a 'Frankenstein' of different messages rather than a strongly built envelope - which is what was causing your issue.

Comment: I am getting an error <faultcode>soap:MustUnderstand</faultcode> <faultstring>SOAP header Action was not understood.</faultstring> when I try to run this. The line breaks were causing an issue and I removed all of those, but no luck still. Does this still work for you? I have another soap envelope that returns 200 but doesn't return any data.

Comment: Dumb error. I had my SOAPAction in headers set to Create. I got it working.